# Making custom create action

Tags: php, yii

In my app, I need to make a table(CGridView) having few columns and a column with button. When I click the button, it should perform create action on model "studentKurs". So, I pass the arguments to the table, and as I see, the function is executed. What fails is my model validation, even though I pass arguments by GET and retrieve them in the actionCreateCustom method I made and populate $model fields with them. What am I missing?

Here is the part from the table in which I create URL:

```
array(
    'class'    => 'CButtonColumn',
    'template' => '{add}',
    'buttons'  => array(
        'add' => array(
            'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("studentKurs/createCustom", 
                      array(
                        "student_id"    => $data[\'id\'],
                        "predmet_naziv" => $_GET[\'predmet_naziv\'],
                        "id_stud_prog"  => $data[\'id_stud_prog\'],
                        "id_nivo_stud"  => $data[\'id_nivo_stud\'],
                        "stud_god_god"  => $_GET[\'stud_god_god\']
                      )
                    )',
        ),
    ),
),
```

Function from controller:

```
public function actionCreateCustom($student_id, $predmet_naziv, $id_stud_prog, $id_nivo_stud, $stud_god_god)
{
    $model=new StudentKurs;

    $model['predmet_naziv'] = $predmet_naziv;
    $model['id_stud_prog'] = $id_stud_prog;
    $model['id_nivo_stud'] = $id_nivo_stud;
    $model['stud_god_god'] = $stud_god_god;
    $model['student_id'] = $student_id;

    $model['ocjena'] = '';
    $model['polozeno'] = '';

    if($model->validate())
    {
        echo "OK";
        $this->saveModel($model);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR";
    }
        //$this->refresh();
}
```

ERROR message gets echoed on my screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the validation errors this way

```
if ($model->validate()) {
  // all inputs are valid
 } else {
 // validation failed: $errors is an array containing error messages
   $errors = $model->errors;
   var_dump($errors);
  }
```

or (trivial way) you can comment selectively your rule for investigatin the responsable ..

Comment: You saved me. One of two fields I set empty could not be set and the message about that was printed. Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't do it in first 10 minutes, it didn't allow me to. Thanks again :)